# Openshift : I am trying to run rhc setup on linux. Am getting username and password error message

Tags: openshift

I am trying to setup openshift on ubuntu. When i ran rhc setup, asked for username and password, it throws username and password error message. I logged in using the github username. Please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `rhc` program is for the old OpenShift 2 and not the newer OpenShift 3 which is currently in developer preview for online and which it sounds like you are trying to use.

If you want the newer OpenShift version, ignore all documentation you find that talks about `rhc`. The command line client for OpenShift 3 is `oc`. Even when you use it, for the developer preview, the `oc login` doesn't take the login/password for GitHub. Instead you need to login into the web console after having logged into GitHub. You can then get access to a token you use to login from the command line.

For general usage of OpenShift 3, I would suggest perhaps you start out reading the free eBook at:

- https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html

Just ignore the bits about local VM and use the online developer preview version instead and take note of what I say above about how login works, as is different to what the book describes when using the VM.

General documentation for OpenShift 3 can be found at:

- https://docs.openshift.com/online/welcome/index.html